# Flutter and Google Sing in: Invalid image data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I have implemented Google Authentication with FlutterFire. I use the [official package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) to sing in users.

However, if I navigate to a page where the **user profile picture is seen** and try to render the `GoogleUserCircleAvatarar`, although the page seems to be working just fine, I get an error in the console:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
Exception: Invalid image data
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

On the screen, it takes a few milliseconds, to load up the picture. Before it's loaded, I can see the placeholder image (First letter of the users initials on a filled background) next to the user's name and email address (so the currentUser is loaded)  which transitions to the user profile picture. As I am using the recommended Widget, I am confused how should I prevent the error from happening.

Code:

```
if (widget.userService.currentUser != null) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: GoogleUserCircleAvatar(
              identity: widget.userService.currentUser,
            ),
            title: Text(widget.userService.currentUser.displayName ?? ''),
            subtitle: Text(widget.userService.currentUser.email ?? ''),
          ),
          const Text("Signed in successfully."),
          RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('SIGN OUT'),
            onPressed: _handleSignOut,
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      ...
```

`currentUser` object is created with the official API:

```
      currentUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
```

and my `pubspec.yml`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+1
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  google_sign_in: "^4.5.1"
  firebase_core: "^0.5.0+1"
  firebase_auth: "^0.18.1+2"
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue should've resolved on the latest version of the [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) plugin. More details of the fix for the issue is discussed on this [pull request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55639).